# Spring Cloud Cannot Load Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I deployed [this](http://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics) Spring application][1](http://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics) on a kubernetes cluster with `kompose up`.  Once it was deployed, the pods for a number of the services would enter a CrashLoopBackoff state.  The services I've had problems with are the account service, monitoring service, notification service, and statistics service.  It appears that when the services start up, they run into the following error:

```
2017-11-15 22:10:52.857  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.p.monitoring.MonitoringApplication     : Started MonitoringApplication in 0.511 seconds (JVM running for 8.579)
2017-11-15 22:10:52.882  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.r.RabbitMessageChannelBinder   : declaring queue for inbound: springCloudHystrixStream.anonymous.oCdNGHmBRPO_Z3LMusKS2Q, bound to: springCloudHystrixStream
2017-11-15 22:11:52.953  WARN 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

The full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/BFV172Uq). Any help is greatly appreciated.  I assume this is a Spring/Java related issue but it may be a Kubernetes related issue as well given that the application was designed to run on docker swarm.

Comment: What's the state of pods? if it is a running or CrashLoopBackOff ? Could you please add that to question?

Comment: Will do, thank you